# Build failed by placing xml code inside <layout></layout> while using databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I want to use databinding in my recyclereview row based on [codelab courses](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-interacting-with-items/#3). What I achieved now is showing data on rows with viewbinding for item rows. I have an xml row with name `layout_row_lesson.xml` and It's binding class `LayoutRowLessonBinding` generated and data in adapter correctly set to views.
My xml is something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
.
.
<SomeViews>
.
.
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But error comes when I try to use data binding and change my xml to something lik this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    .
    .
    <SomeViews>
    .
    .
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

as you can see after placing my code between `<layout>` and `</layout>` and trying to rebuild app this error shows

```
...\app\databinding\LayoutRowLessonBinding.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
public abstract class LayoutRowLessonBinding extends ViewDataBinding {
```

Whats I did to solve but haven't succeed is:
 1. Invalidate caches and restart
 2. Renaming layout file name
 3. Clean & rebuild
 4. Restart android studio
 5. Delete build folder

and to clearify viewbind is enabled:

```
 viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to enable data binding

```
 dataBinding {
        enabled = true
 }
```